# Similarity Between Bases a and b

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If a number is represented as 1234 in base $a$ and as 1020304 in base $b$, what can you say about bases a and b?

Attempt at solution:

If we convert each of the representations of the given number to base 10 and equate the results, we obtain:

$$a^3+2a^2+3a=b^6+2b^4+3b^2$$

I am not certain where to proceed from here.

Comment: You can say that $a=b^2$.

Comment: Could you be more explicit, as to how you arrived at this conclusion?

Comment: That they are both larger than $4$.

Answer (score 0):

> $$a^3+2a^2+3a=b^6+2b^4+3b^2$$

That pretty much closes it. Move to one side, use $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+ \cdots)$ then:

$$
(b^2-a)(b^4+b^2a+a^2+2b^2+2a+3) = 0
$$

Note that the second factor is strictly positive, so you are left with $b^2=a$ where $a \gt 4$ (for the digit $4$ to be a valid digit in base $a$).

Comment: Why does $a$ need to be greater than 4?

Comment: @Analysis15: The answer is very explicit about it - **for the digit $4$ to be a valid digit in base $a$**.